# Devise new users not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, registration

I am building an application in which only admin accounts are allowed to create new user accounts. I am using devise 4.2 for authentication and cancancan for authorization with rails 4.2.6. My issue is that new users are not being created, and I am not receiving any error messages so have no clue what is going wrong.
My registration controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]
  #before_action :authorize_admin, only: [:create, :new, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    super
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
        #sign_up(resource_name, resource)
         respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
       else
         set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
         expire_data_after_sign_in!
         respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
       end
     else
       clean_up_passwords resource
       set_minimum_password_length
       respond_with resource
    end
   end

  # GET /resource/edit
  def edit
     super
  end

  # PUT /resource
  def update
     super
  end

  # DELETE /resource
  def destroy
    super
  end

  def cancel
    super
  end

  protected

  def configure_sign_up_params
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
  end

  def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name])
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    super(resource)
  end

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    super(resource)
  end
end
```

My view:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :name %>
     <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email%>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :password %>
     <% if @minimum_password_length %>
     <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
     <% end %><br />
     <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
     <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

I commented out the line that signs in a new user on account creation because I was getting flash messages saying "You are already logged in" when creating a new user while logged in as an admin which lead me to believe this was why new users are not being saved. This appears to be incorrect, although I am still getting flash messages saying the same thing when I try to make a new user. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your goal is to allow an admin user to create users.  In that case, you need to actually create a user, not a registration.  This means, in one of your controller methods (probably in `UsersController`) you would have something like:

```
def create
  @user = User.create params
end
```

When you create a new *registration* in `Users::RegistrationsController`, it means you are trying to register as a new user, but since you're already signed in, devise prevents it.